# Install qwebengine on mac

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, homebrew

I'm using qwebengine in my Qt5 program.
I use this command to install qt on my travis-ci env:
`HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install qt5 qt5-qtwebengine --verbose; fi`
However it tells me: `Error: No available formula with the name "qt5-qtwebengine"`
How to instaall qtwebengine properly by brew?

Comment: Qt is at its best when installed from qt.io

Comment: It's on travis-ci. I can't install from qt.io on travis-ci.

Comment: Try to brew install `qt` ... you have outdated formulae listed.

Comment: brew install qt doesn't cotain qwebengine.

Comment: Calling brew update and then brew install qt5 solved this. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I was just going to say... the fix was patched in two weeks ago and you need to brew update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was patched in two weeks ago and you will need to `brew update` before you `brew install qt`